# How to sort map data keyed by date and time and summarize by date and/or hour-of-day?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a map of integer data where the keys are a date and time in a format like:

> May 15, 2015 5:46 PM

So for example I have:

> May 15, 2015 5:46 PM, 25
>   May 15, 2015 5:50 PM, 25
>   May 15, 2015 6:15 PM, 30
>   May 15, 2015 8:05 PM, 40
>   May 15, 2015 10:46 PM, 10
>   May 15, 2015 5:10 AM, 5

Is there a way to sort this data by hours? So I can have something like:

> 5PM, 55
>   6PM, 30
>   8PM, 40
>   10PM, 10

and also the same thing for dates?

Comment: Convert them to `LocalDateTime` or `LocalTime` and compare them, maybe using a `List` a `Collections.sort`...

Comment: Note this is not only sort, but aggregation as well.

Comment: Extract the hour(e.g by regexp) as the key of record, change it to 24 hour format(e.g 5PM=17), then sort by key.

Comment: If you use database you can get Data by using Orderby asc or dsc

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Integer> originalMap = ... // the map you mentioned
Map<String, Integer> aggregationMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);

// change "ha" to "yyyyMMdd" if you wanna do aggregation by date
DateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ha", Locale.US);
Iterator<String> it = originalMap.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String k = it.next();
    int v = originalMap.get(k);
    String key = sdf2.format(sdf.parse(k));
    Integer value = aggregationMap.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        aggregationMap.put(key, v);
    } else {
        aggregationMap.put(key, v + value);
    }
}

// TODO dump aggregationMap to see the result
```

Comment: What about the _sorting_ aspect of the original question?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to do this, assuming you're using an implementing class of `java.util.Map`, would be to:

1. Get the set of map entries using the `entrySet()` method.
2. Write a custom `Comparator` class to sort the datetime entries by the hours in ascending order. Separately you can write one to sort by dates.
3. Create a TreeSet (an implementation of `SortableSet`), using the constructor that initializes the TreeSet with your custom `Comparator`.
4. Use `TreeSet.addAll()` to copy and sort the entries from the `Set<Map.Entry>` you obtained in step 1.

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a data structure that's an exact copy of your existing map, you could get the `keySet` and sort just the keys. Then when you want to access the map elements in order, you could iterate through your sorted `keySet` and pull the corresponding numbers out of the map you already have.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to assume that your raw data is stored in a `Map<String, Integer>` that is a member field called `rawData`.  Using Java 8, here is the heart of your desired aggregate summary and sorting logic:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T> & Temporal> SortedMap<T, Integer> summarize(
    DateTimeFormatter keyFormat,
    Function<LocalDateTime, ? extends T> keyTransform)
{
    SortedMap<T, Integer> summaryData = new TreeMap<>();

    rawData.forEach((k, v) -> {
        LocalDateTime rawDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(k, keyFormat);
        T summaryKey = keyTransform.apply(rawDateTime);
        summaryData.merge(summaryKey, v, (x, y) -> x + y);
    });

    return summaryData;
}
```

This method processes that `rawData` map and returns a sorted map whose keys are a `Temporal` type -- for example, a `LocalDate` with no time component, or a `LocalTime` with no date component.  In order to determine which behavior, you must pass in two arguments:

1. A format object that describes how to interpret the `String` key of the raw data as a `LocalDateTime`.
2. A transformation function that then converts the `LocalDateTime` into your aggregate keys at your desired level of granularity.

The call to `summaryData.merge(...)` takes care of adding the key and value the first time; when the same key is merged again, the provided lambda expression combines the prior and new values -- in your case, you simply want to add the two.

The key type (such as `LocalDate`) must also be `Comparable` so that the sorted map implementation will do the sorting automatically.  Here's a helper method that uses the above to generate the desired output in your question, by hour of day.  The raw data key formatter is still required as input:

```
void printSummaryByHour(DateTimeFormatter rawKeyFormat)
{
    SortedMap<LocalTime, Integer> summary =
        summarize(
            rawKeyFormat,
            key -> LocalTime.of(key.getHour(), 0) // ignore date, minutes, seconds, etc.
        );

    DateTimeFormatter summaryKeyFormat =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h a", Locale.US); // e.g. "7 PM"
    print(summary, summaryKeyFormat::format);
}
```

The call to the `summarize` method uses a *lambda expression* to map the `LocalDateTime` into a `LocalTime` (dropping the date) that always ignores the minute value and only keeps the hour.  It then passes the resulting sorted set to a method I'll cover later to output to the console, but in all likelihood your real program will want to do more than print to the screen.

Your question didn't give an example of your expected output "by date", so I'll assume that you want discrete days like "May 15, 2015" and not aggregate across months or anything special -- just summarize entire 24-hour periods.  This is easily done with a different version of the above method, changing only the summary key type, summary conversion, and output formats:

```
void printSummaryByDate(DateTimeFormatter rawKeyFormat)
{
    SortedMap<LocalDate, Integer> summary =
        summarize(
            rawKeyFormat,
            LocalDateTime::toLocalDate
        );

    DateTimeFormatter summaryKeyFormat =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US); // e.g. "May 15, 2015"
    print(summary, summaryKeyFormat::format);
}
```

The sorted map is now keyed by `LocalDate` instead of `LocalTime`.  The key conversion from date-time to date-only uses a *function reference* instead of a custom lambda expression, with the output format for the summary keys changed accordingly.

To complete the answer, here's the setup scaffolding and `print` helper method:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.Temporal;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class StackOverflow30494397
{
    private final Map<String, Integer> rawData = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        StackOverflow30494397 instance = new StackOverflow30494397();
        instance.rawData.put("May 15, 2015 5:46 PM", 25);
        instance.rawData.put("May 15, 2015 5:50 PM", 25);
        instance.rawData.put("May 15, 2015 6:15 PM", 30);
        instance.rawData.put("May 15, 2015 8:05 PM", 40);
        instance.rawData.put("May 15, 2015 10:46 PM", 10);
        instance.rawData.put("May 15, 2015 5:10 AM", 5);

        DateTimeFormatter rawKeyFormat =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);

        instance.printSummaryByHour(rawKeyFormat);
        instance.printSummaryByDate(rawKeyFormat);
    }

    private <K> void print(Map<K, ?> map, Function<? super K, String> keyFormatter)
    {
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s, %d%n", keyFormatter.apply(k), v));
        System.out.println();
    }

    // INSERT OTHER METHODS (DESCRIBED IN ANSWER) HERE    
}
```

Outputs:

> 5 AM, 5
>      5 PM, 50
>      6 PM, 30
>      8 PM, 40
>      10 PM, 10
>
> May 15, 2015, 135